# Find all those columns which have only  null values, in a MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql

The situation is as follows:

I have a substantial number of tables, with each a substantial number of columns. I need to deal with this old and to-be-deprecated database for a new system, and I'm looking for a way to eliminate all columns that have - apparently - never been in use.

I wanna do this by filtering out all columns that have a value on any given row, leaving me with a set of columns where the value is NULL in all rows. Of course I could manually sort every column descending, but that'd take too long as I'm dealing with loads of tables and columns. I estimate it to be 400 tables with up to 50 (!) columns per table.

Is there any way I can get this information from the information_schema?

**EDIT:**

Here's an example:

```
column_a    column_b    column_c    column_d
NULL        NULL        NULL        1
NULL        1           NULL        1
NULL        1           NULL        NULL
NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL
```

The output should be 'column_a' and 'column_c', for being the only columns without any filled in values.

Comment: I think its too tough to be solved by any single query. You need a procedure. Is it acceptable to do this through a procedure or only query?

Comment: No problem at all, might be even better cause I can then easily pass another table name.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can avoid using a procedure by dynamically creating (from the [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/columns-table.html) table) a string that contains the SQL you wish to execute, then [preparing a statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) from that string and executing it.

The SQL we wish to build will look like:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT 'tableA' AS `table`,
         IF(COUNT(`column_a`), NULL, 'column_a') AS `column`
  FROM   tableA
UNION ALL
  SELECT 'tableB' AS `table`,
         IF(COUNT(`column_b`), NULL, 'column_b') AS `column`
  FROM   tableB
UNION ALL
  -- etc.
) t WHERE `column` IS NOT NULL
```

This can be done using the following:

```
SET group_concat_max_len = 4294967295; -- to overcome default 1KB limitation

SELECT CONCAT(
         'SELECT * FROM ('
       ,  GROUP_CONCAT(
            'SELECT ', QUOTE(TABLE_NAME), ' AS `table`,'
          , 'IF('
          ,   'COUNT(`', REPLACE(COLUMN_NAME, '`', '``'), '`),'
          ,   'NULL,'
          ,    QUOTE(COLUMN_NAME)
          , ') AS `column` '
          , 'FROM `', REPLACE(TABLE_NAME, '`', '``'), '`'
          SEPARATOR ' UNION ALL '
         )
       , ') t WHERE `column` IS NOT NULL'
       )
INTO   @sql
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE  TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE();

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/953c4/11/2).

Comment: Despite the fact your example is working (on SQLFiddle), it's (way) too heavy for my database. It says: memory exhausted right away... I don't think there's any way around that with your proposed method.

Comment: @Robinv.G.: Except perhaps tweaking MySQL's configuration parameters and/or adding more memory to the server... but yes, you are looking to investigate ~400*50=20k columns, which will create a very large query.  If a single query is too large, you could focus on a subset of your tables at a time e.g. by changing the `WHERE` clause to `TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE() AND TABLE_NAME BETWEEN 'A' AND 'C'`.  Or else you will have to use a looping construct e.g. in a stored procedure - there's no other way.

Comment: Thank you for your effert, I'll play around with it a little!

Comment: I got this to work table for table, which is an excellent result for my needs. It's no problem to do it table for table. Thanks again!

Comment: @eggyal. Please check my question and and my solution on this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12556713/sql-query-for-creating-backup-of-mysql-database-statedata/12572377#12572377 .  It is some similar to my answer on this post. I need that answer to be similar to your on this post :)

Comment: Without asking a new question, how does this look like for postgresql dialect?

Comment: this is why I hate SQL. It takes that much code to do one tiny, simple task.

Answer (score 12):

I am not an expert in SQL procedures, hence giving general idea using SQL queries and a PHP/python script.

- use `SHOW TABLES` or some other query on `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` database to get all tables in your database `MY_DATABASE`
- do a query to generate a statement to get all column names in a particular table, this will be used in next query.

> ```
>  SELECT Group_concat(Concat( "MAX(", column_name, ")" ))
>          FROM   information_schema.columns
>          WHERE  table_schema = 'MY_DATABSE'
>                 AND table_name = 'MY_TABLE'
>          ORDER  BY table_name,ordinal_position
> ```

- You will get an output like     `MAX(column_a),MAX(column_b),MAX(column_c),MAX(column_d)`
- Use this output to generate final query :

> SELECT Max(column_a),   Max(column_b),   Max(column_c), Max(column_d)  FROM  MY_DATABASE.MY_TABLE

The output would be :

```
   MAX(column_a)    MAX(column_b)   MAX(column_c)   MAX(column_d)
     NULL            1           NULL                1
```

- All the columns with Max value as `NULL` are the ones which have all values `NULL`

Comment: This is an interesting approach (for which: +1), but feels a little unsatisfying. It indeed requires a language to glue it all together. It might be possible in pure SQL (encapsulating this method in an SP), but it'd probably end up being lengthy and rather ugly. I'm gonna wait for other answers before accepting this one. Thanks for this approach tho. :)

Comment: @Robinv.G. it is surely possible in a Stored Procedure,however a scripting language would provide more control and cleaner flow.

Answer (score 4):

You can take advantage of the behavior of *COUNT* aggregate function regarding NULLs. By passing the field as argument, the *COUNT* function returns the number of non-NULL values while *COUNT(*)* returns the total number of rows. Thus you can calculate the ratio of NULL to "acceptable" values.

I will give an example with the following table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `t1` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `col_1` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
   `col_2` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ;

-- let's fill the table with random values
INSERT INTO t1(col_1,col_2) VALUES(1,2);
INSERT INTO t1(col_1,col_2) 
SELECT 
IF(RAND() > 0.5, NULL ,FLOOR(RAND()*1000), 
IF(RAND() > 0.5, NULL ,FLOOR(RAND()*1000) FROM t1;

-- run the last INSERT-SELECT statement a few times
SELECT COUNT(col_1)/COUNT(*) AS col_1_ratio, 
COUNT(col_2)/COUNT(*) AS col_2_ratio FROM t1;
```

You can write a function that automatically constructs a query from the 
INFORMATION_SCHEMA database by passing the table name as input variable.
Here's how to obtain the structure data directly from INFORMATION_SCHEMA tables:

```
SET @query:=CONCAT("SELECT @column_list:=GROUP_CONCAT(col) FROM (
SELECT CONCAT('COUNT(',c.COLUMN_NAME,')/COUNT(*)') AS col
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c 
WHERE NOT COLUMN_KEY IN('PRI') AND TABLE_SCHEMA=DATABASE() 
AND TABLE_NAME='t1' ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION ) q");
PREPARE COLUMN_SELECT FROM @query;
EXECUTE COLUMN_SELECT;
SET @null_counters_sql := CONCAT('SELECT ',@column_list, ' FROM t1');
PREPARE NULL_COUNTERS FROM @null_counters_sql;
EXECUTE NULL_COUNTERS;
```

Comment: The effort looks good, though I can't get this to work on MySQL. I'll dive in to this tomorrow. The second to last line gives a syntax error.

Comment: I reviewed my answer, please check again.

Comment: I've been playing with it, and it does concatenate all the COUNTs, but it doesn't run as a query. The output I get is this:
`COUNT(column)/COUNT(*)` for each column. It doesn't actually execute. Do you know where to look?

Comment: Also, it gives me a warning (for query 1, 2, 4 and 5) that "COUN" is an unknown column. "COUN", not "COUNT". Strange thing is: I can't find "COUN" with the missing T anywhere..

Comment: Try running the query on INFORMATION_SCHEMA by itself. 
SELECT CONCAT('COUNT(',c.COLUMN_NAME,')/COUNT(*)') AS col
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c 
WHERE NOT COLUMN_KEY IN('PRI') AND TABLE_SCHEMA=DATABASE() 
AND TABLE_NAME='t1' ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION

Remember to set  your database first, by executing a USE statement or simply replace DATABASE() with the name of your DB.

Answer (score 4):

[**SQL Fiddle Demo Link**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dd076/1)

I have created 4 tables. Three for demo and one `nullcolumns` is the compulsory part of solution. Among three tables, only `salary` and `dept` have columns with all values null (you may have a look at their script).

The compulsory table and the procedure are given at the end

You can copy paste and run (the compulsory part or all) as sql (just you have to change the delimiter to //) in your desired database on your localhost and then  --- `call get();` and see the results

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dept` (
  `did` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `dname` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`did`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO `dept` (`did`, `dname`) VALUES
(1, NULL),
(2, NULL),
(3, NULL),
(4, NULL),
(5, NULL);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `emp` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ename` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `did` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ename`),
  KEY `deptid` (`did`),
  KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;


INSERT INTO `emp` (`id`, `ename`, `did`) VALUES
(1, 'e1', 4),
(2, 'e2', 4),
(3, 'e3', 2),
(4, 'e4', 4),
(5, 'e5', 3);


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `salary` (
  `EmpCode` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `Amount` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Date` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `salary` (`EmpCode`, `Amount`, `Date`) VALUES
('1', 344, NULL),
('2', NULL, NULL);

------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `nullcolumns` (
  `Table_Name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `Column_Name` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--Only one procedure Now
CREATE PROCEDURE get(dn varchar(100))
BEGIN
declare c1 int; declare b1 int default 0; declare tn varchar(30);
declare c2 int; declare b2 int; declare cn varchar(30);

select count(*) into c1 from information_schema.tables where table_schema=dn;
delete from nullcolumns;
while b1<c1 do
select table_name into tn from information_schema.tables where
table_schema=dn limit b1,1;        

select count(*) into c2 from information_schema.columns where
table_schema=dn and table_name=tn;
set b2=0;
while b2<c2 do
select column_name into cn from information_schema.columns where
table_schema=dn and table_name=tn limit b2,1;

set @nor := 0;
set @query := concat("select count(*) into @nor from ", dn,".",tn);
prepare s1 from @query;
execute s1;deallocate prepare s1;

if @nor>0 then set @res := 0;
set @query := concat("select ((select max(",cn,") from ", dn,".",tn,")
is NULL) into @res");
prepare s1 from @query;
execute s1;deallocate prepare s1;

if @res=1 then
insert into nullcolumns values(tn,cn);
end if; end if;

set b2=b2+1;
end while;

set b1=b1+1;
end while;
select * from nullcolumns;
END;
```

You can easily execute stored procedure easily as sql in your phpmyadin 'as it is' just change the Delimiters (at the bottom of SQL quesry box) to // Then

```
call get();
```

And **Enjoy** :)

You can see Now the table `nullcolumns` showing all columns having 100/100 null values along with the table Names

In procedure code `if @nor>0` restricts that no empty table should be included in results you can remove that restriction.

Comment: If you face any difficulty with stored procedures or anything else, I will be happy to guide further

Comment: Wow, this really is a neat piece of SQL! I'm struggling to get it to work on MySQL (sigh...) now (the LIMIT B,1 doesn't work), but this is a job well done!

Comment: I have edited the code to make one procedure instead of three. One procedure also allowed me to upload demo on sqlfiddle @Robinv.G.

Comment: Do you see any chance testing this on MySQL? I can't get this to work. :(

Comment: I accepted Eggyal's solution, but special thanks to you for your very good effort!

Comment: @Robinv.G. eggyal's solution looks better. Although My code is also working on sqlfiddle you might have looked. I was not here. Otherwise i could make it working for you if you could upload your schema. However Sad thing that it was first good chance for me to give acceptable solution to bounty question and I had hours of effort for this. But good is that i have learned many things during this effort. Thanks for very nice response. I got reward of my hours spent with the benefit of learning and your nice response :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this with GROUP_CONCAT and GROUP BY:

```
select length(replace(GROUP_CONCAT(my_col), ',', ''))
from my_table
group by my_col
```

(*untested*)

**EDIT**: the docs don't seem to state that GROUP_CONCAT needs a corresponding GROUP BY, so try this:

```
select 
    length(replace(GROUP_CONCAT(col_a), ',', '')) as len_a
    , length(replace(GROUP_CONCAT(col_b), ',', '')) as len_b
    , length(replace(GROUP_CONCAT(col_c), ',', '')) as Len_c
from my_table
```

Comment: This is per column, I need it table wide for _every_ column, leaving me with a set of columns without values. I'll expand my original post with an example.

Comment: Response to your edit: this still requires manual insertion of all columns. Hardly an option, but thanks.

Comment: It would seem this works? `SELECT w as 'non empty cols',LENGTH(REPLACE(w, ',', '')) FROM (SELECT column_name as w FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema = "my_database" AND table_name = "my_table" ORDER BY table_name,ordinal_position ) t;`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a prepared statement fed by MySQL's information scheme:

```
SET @TABLE_NAME= '...';

SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;

SELECT 
CONCAT('SELECT * FROM (', 
    Group_concat(CONCAT("SELECT '", COLUMN_NAME, "' AS n, MAX(", COLUMN_NAME, ") AS v FROM ", @TABLE_NAME ) SEPARATOR ' UNION ALL ')
    , ") x WHERE v IS NOT null"
)
INTO @q
FROM   information_schema.columns
WHERE  table_schema = (SELECT DATABASE())
AND table_name = @TABLE_NAME
ORDER  BY table_name,ordinal_position
;

         
PREPARE ps FROM @q;
EXECUTE ps;
```

Answer (score -2):

```
select column_name
from user_tab_columns
where table_name='Table_name' and num_nulls>=1;
```

Just by simple query you will get those two columns.