# Database backup SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, database-backups

I need to fetch data from database for backup in the form of insert statements

I need to do it on a button click in c#. So i think an sql query or stored procedure will be appropriate to do this, rather than mysqldump.

Secondly I need them for **all tables**. Instead of writing table and column names. They should be fetched from information_schema, because the query will not need to be changed for different scema

If there already exists a solution, please guide me.

**Update** : I have prepared a solution, it is posted, still looking for the better one.

Comment: I am working on it and have not found any such plugin. So hep me if it is already done using sql-query. I am taking my time and seems it will take a lot. Still may not be able to get it perfectly working in long period :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### To get Data of whole database - SqlFiddle Demo




#### To get data of only one table - - SqlFiddle Demo

I have made a complex but acceptable solution. **But needs improvement**.

This is a complex procedure with complex coding especially the query which fetches all rows of all columns into a single result by `group_concat` and formats with a complex concatenation.

Need it simplified, efficient and working in all scenarios.

**Some details of my solution** : Following is the important part, other is just conditions/Looping (I am not handy with documentation also it needs time and suggestions, someone might help me in its formatting  and improvement, Sorry for any inconvenience, however I will be glad for any help from you and me)

Note: group_concat(yourColumn separator ' --anySeparator-- ') is merging all rows of your column as one such that Rows are separated by --anySeparator--

```
select group_concat(column_name separator '`,`') into @cns1 from
information_schema.columns where table_schema=dn and table_name=@tn;
```

1 : column_names are got as a single value separated by

```
`,` => @cs1 = id`,`ename`,`did

select group_concat(column_name separator '`,"\',\'",`') into @cns2
from information_schema.columns where table_schema=dn and table_name=@tn;
```

2 : column_names are got as a single value separated by

```
`','` => @cn2  = id`','`ename`','`did

set @cns1=concat("`",@cns1,"`");    set @cns2=concat("`",@cns2,"`");
```

3: Missing letter (`) is put at beginning and end of Column names

```
set @res=concat(@res," insert into ",@tn,"(",@cns1,") values ('");
```

4: Simply makes `res= " insert into emp(``id` `,` `ename` `,``did` `) values("` Here you can see why have I put separators (MySql Formatting is achieved)

```
set @temp := '';
set @q := concat("select group_concat(concat(",@cns2,") separator \"'),('\")
 from ",dn,".",@tn, " into @temp");
```

**Above is the most crucial statement** It gets all data rows from table as rows of a single column and further these rows are merged being separated by `'),('`

5.1 `concat(",@cns2,")` gets values of all columns in a single one.

5.2  After outer most concat now @q is

```
 @q = "select group_concat(`id`','`ename`','`,did` separator '),(' from 
mydb.emp into @temp";
```

5.3 : group_concat will merge all rows of that combined column into one value.
Columns values will be joined through separators existing in @cns2 and rows level joining will be with `'),('`

```
prepare s1 from @q;
execute s1;deallocate prepare s1;
set @res = concat(@res,@temp,");");
```

@q is executed

```
set @res = concat(@res,@temp,");");
```

6 : And We will get result as

```
 res was = insert into emp(`id`,`ename`,`did`) values ('
@temp = 1','e1','4'),('2','e2','4'),
('3','e3','2'),('4','e4','4'),('5','e5','3
```

And after `@res = concat(@res,@temp,");");` we get

```
 insert into emp(`id`,`ename`,`did`) values ('1','e1','4'),('2','e2','4'),
('3','e3','2'),('4','e4','4'),('5','e5','3);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select concat("insert into users (id,name,password) values ('",id,"'"), 
concat(",'",username,"'"),
concat(",'",password,"'),") INTO OUTFILE 'c:\\datas\\asd.txt' from users
```