# How To Fill All Null Values In Table with Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sqldatatypes

thanks for review this

i have easily problem , i know it will solve by you frinds

i have a table with 14 columns , 8 of cols are numeric (int , biging , numeric(18,0)) and 
other cols data type are in text value such as char(10), varchar(255),Nvarchar(4000)
 this table filled by same random value and in all cols (except ID) have lot of null value .

i want make one or more Stored Procedure that Fill all null cell in numeric columns to 0 and
all nulls in string columns to 'no value'.

if this SP will return count of all null values in all columns , its amazing

thanks so much

Comment: Is this a homework problem?  Can you provide an example of the output that you want?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12091272/find-all-those-columns-which-have-only-null-values-in-a-mysql-table

Comment: It is usually better to keep the data clean and do these kinds of substitutions at query-time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a loop in store procedure but best way is you check all column for null value because may be any column have various data type.

i hope this be helpful .

Comment: thank user... . you right this table have some type and i forget it

Answer (score 1):

```
Update Table1
set col1='0'
where co1 is null
```

And so on...

Comment: Assuming that `col1` is a numeric column ("Fill all null cell in numeric columns to 0"), why you have used single quote for a numeric/integer constant: `'0'` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can update as stated above but if you need to have a default field as 0 then you should have used default on table creation

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Something
(
    id               INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
    col1        INT DEFAULT 0
)
```

but if its legacy code than on insert proc you could have used like

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spa_CRUDSomething]
    @flag CHAR(1)
   ,  @col1 INT = 0
AS
```

Usually the problem isn't in doing fixes rather on way of fixing the fixes