# How to select just the cols which are NOT NULL ? mysql

Tags: mysql

I have this table :

```
===================
col1 | col2 | col3|
-------------------
  1    NULL    1
  1     1      1
  NULL  NULL   1
  .      .     .
```

I want to write query which will return $result AND $result equal to :

```
$result[0]{  "col1":1  ,  "col3":1               };
$result[1]{  "col1":1  ,  "col2":1  ,  "col3":1  };
$result[2]{  "col3":1                            };
```

How could I do that ?

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/28726/select-column-names-whose-entries-are-not-null

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12091272/find-all-those-columns-which-have-only-null-values-in-a-mysql-table