# select column/paragraph that is not null

Tags: mysql

i have the following which is an adaption from a search here on stackoverflow from this url:
[Find all those columns which have only  null values, in a MySQL table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12091272/find-all-those-columns-which-have-only-null-values-in-a-mysql-table)

```
SELECT CONCAT(
         'SELECT * FROM ('
       ,  GROUP_CONCAT(
            'SELECT ', QUOTE(TABLE_NAME), ' AS `table`,'
          , 'IF('
          ,   'COUNT(`', REPLACE(COLUMN_NAME, '`', '``'), '`),'
          ,   'NULL,'
          ,    QUOTE(COLUMN_NAME)
          , ') AS `column` '
          , 'FROM `', REPLACE(TABLE_NAME, '`', '``'), '`'
          SEPARATOR ' UNION ALL '
         )
       , ') t WHERE `column` IS NOT NULL'
       )
INTO   @sql
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE  TABLE_NAME = 'about';

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

results:

```
+--------------+ 
| table column | 
+--------------+ 
| ----- -----  | 
| about par6   | 
| about par7   | 
| about par8   | 
| about par9   | 
| about par10  | 
+--------------+
```

This diplays two columns:the table name and the column values.
How can i get just the columns which are not null and retrieve their values from the database?

Comment: can you show your outcome? results?

Comment: @JohnRuddell here are the results:+------------------+
| table   column   |
+------------------+
| ------  -------- |
| about   par6     |
| about   par7     |
| about   par8     |
| about   par9     |
| about   par10    |
+------------------+

Comment: so I guess the next question is why are you doing the select this way? do you need to concat a string and execute it?